# Group concat in spark scala dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

Table contains following list of columns.

| ID | A_ID | DESC | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | PQ | 2023-05-02 10:30:40 |
| 100 | 200 | XY | 2023-04-30 21:20:26 |
| 100 | 200 | AB | 2023-04-11 15:19:10 |
| 100 | 200 | DE | 2023-05-02 13:52:23 |
| 100 | 201 | LM | 2023-04-30 21:20:26 |
| 100 | 201 | FH | 2023-04-11 15:19:10 |
| 100 | 201 | OP | 2023-05-02 13:52:23 |
| 101 | 301 | YQ | 2023-05-02 11:52:23 |

Need the output in below format in spark scala dataframe. Sorting should be on Date field.

| ID | A_ID | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200;201 | INTERNAL : 200 DESCRIPTION: 2023-04-11 15:19:10:AB 2023-04-30 21:20:26:XY 2023-05-02 10:30:40:PQ 2023-05-02 13:52:23:DE INTERNAL : 201 DESCRIPTION: 2023-04-11 15:19:10:FH 2023-04-30 21:20:26:LM 2023-05-02 13:52:23:OP |
| 101 | 301 | INTERNAL : 301 DESCRIPTION: 2023-05-02 11:52:23:YQ |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add the code.

Comment: val df=dfTemp.orderBy($"ID".asc,$"A_ID".asc,$"DATE".asc).groupBy($"ID")
      .agg(concat_ws(";",collect_set("A_ID")).as("A_ID"),collect_set(concat_ws(":",$"DATE",$"DESC")).as("COMMENT"))

Comment: @ollimandoliini I have tried above mentioned code which gives me  A_ID in appropriate format but I could not form the Comment. Can you pls help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `groupBy`s: first group by `ID` and `A_ID`, do the necessary string operations for the comment and then group by `ID` again:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val spark = ...
import spark.implicits._
val df = ...

df.groupBy("ID", "A_ID")                                           //first group by
  .agg(collect_list(concat_ws(":",'DATE, 'DESC)).alias("COMMENT"))
  .withColumn("COMMENT", concat_ws("\n", array_sort('COMMENT)))    //combine the comments for an A_ID
  .withColumn("COMMENT", concat(lit("INTERNAL: "), 'A_ID,          //add the intro to the comments
                               lit(" DESCRIPTION: "), 'COMMENT))
  .orderBy('ID, 'A_ID)
  .groupBy('ID)                                                    //second group by
  .agg(concat_ws(";",collect_list('A_ID)).alias("A_ID"),           //combine all comments for an ID
      concat_ws("\n", collect_list('COMMENT)).alias("COMMENT"))
  .show(truncate=false)
```

Output (manually formatted because `show` does not handle well multi-line strings):

```
+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|ID |A_ID   |COMMENT                                           |
+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|101|301    |INTERNAL: 301 DESCRIPTION: 2023-05-02 11:52:23:YQ                                                                                                                                                                     |
|100|200;201|INTERNAL: 200 DESCRIPTION: 2023-04-11 15:19:10:AB
             2023-04-30 21:20:26:XY
             2023-05-02 10:30:40:PQ
             2023-05-02 13:52:23:DE
             INTERNAL: 201 DESCRIPTION: 2023-04-11 15:19:10:FH
             2023-04-30 21:20:26:LM
             2023-05-02 13:52:23:OP|
+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
```